# What's the 'in-between' solution between a bunch of spreadsheets and a relational database?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

Most would be familiar with how Excel/Libreoffice Calc is (mis-)used throughout the business world. It starts off with a simple spreadsheet or two containing half a dozen columns, and eventually someone starts using VLOOKUP, filters, array formulae...

What is normally being attempted is to have some of the functionality of a relational database. A quick example is a list of members of some organisation. The first sheet may be just their personal details. And then a new sheet is used for simple attendance taking (probably referencing the first sheet for the actual names), and another sheet is used to keep track of current projects (who is responsible for what), then another sheet for simple budgets for said project. Sometimes these would be separate workbooks which either rely on manual reconciliation or some inter-workbook formulae (brittle). After a year or so, more workbooks/sheets spawn which collate the data in these spreadsheets into some form of report, using date filters, SUMIF, things like that.

Arguably, a relational database is eventually more suitable. Access or Libreoffice Base. It's quite a high hurdle to switch though, given the different user paradigms. Are there any 'in-between' solutions for non-CS/technical background users who are already comfortable with Excel/Calc but intimidated by a full blown database application?

Comment: I understand where you're going, but I think this is a little like asking, "What's in-between a dog and a cat".  Yeah, what you describe happens a lot.  But after it happens the first time, someone should be smart enough the next time to say, "Hey, let's start this one as a database."  If the data is already in tables in the spreadsheet, in good form, they can be imported or converted to database tables.  Then you "just" need to redo the queries and reports.

Comment: As @fixer1234 states, a relational DB offers what you need, and SQL is fairly standardized and much more logical than idiosyncratic spreadsheet commands. It's not difficult to export to Access (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-data-from-excel-to-access-90c35a40-bcc3-46d9-aa7f-4106f78850b4) to LibreOffice Base (https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/56795/can-i-import-an-existing-excel-sheet-into-libre-base/), or to the free (and small) Firebird DB (https://www.easyfrom.net/articles/ms_excel_to_firebird/)

Comment: Microsoft Access *is* the watered down version of a database; a sort of SQL-ey back end and a front end that is like Excel on steroids. It'll never gain traction with an Excel lover; gotta leave them to it, unless the business has an appetite to spend tens of thousands on paying someone to develop something proper. In my experience the answer to that one is: no

Comment: I guess what fixer1234 and DrMoishe Pippik are saying is that biting the bullet and just going to relational DBs is the best solution. @CaiusJard I never thought of Access as being watered down SQL, just... non-standard?

Answer (score 1):

You're not likely to get an answer that is substantially than different from what has already been said in the comments.

What lies between Excel and Access?  More advanced usage of Excel.

PowerQuery and PowerPivot have been available in Excel for more than half a decade.  Combined with hardware improvements that increase performance and allowed MS to improve Excel's upper row limit into the millions - Excel is now more capable of setting you up to fail than ever before.

If you're not already using both of those tools and data management is a priority over data interpretation, then I'd suggest picking up Access.  You'll be missing out on some of the best Excel has to offer but that's what analysts are for.

On the other hand, if you're simply exploring the landscape and your present solution is acceptable for the next couple years, then I'd encourage you to spend the time learning the more powerful side of Excel.  It is the king of ad hoc reporting and analysis.

Comment: Excel tends to have only a short runway between "this is getting slow" to "holy crap this no longer works", in my experience. And my current project is primarily data management rather than interpretation, yes, hence why I'm considering Access/Base etc. I'd really just add some Postgres tables but trying to teach others to use it would require more time than I have...

Comment: That's why you write a UI in some programming language (could be access; it can ODBC to other RDBMSs, heck it could even be Excel/macros but you're after doing it properly, right?), set yourself up as a consultant and earn some serious cash when they want changes ;)